# document.write this line of code Mon-Sat and this line of code on Sundays

Tags: javascript, date, document.write

Basically, I have this:

```
document.write('DIVS/HTML go here')
```

And ONLY on Sundays, I want it to be:

```
document.write(' ')
```

Empty, but still there in case I do want to fill it with something for that particular day.

How would I accomplish this in my JS file?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (new Date().getDay() == 0)
{
    /* it's Sunday */
}
else
{
    /* it's not Sunday */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if((new Date()).getDay() >=1)
{
    // Monday - Saturday
    document.write('DIVS/HTML go here');
}
else
{
    // Sunday
    document.write(' ');
}
```